# Could I make keep the animation position as the new position for an object?

Tags: animation, physics, keyframes, cloth-simulation, force-fields

I'm trying to simulate a cloth patch which is a rectangle to "stick" to something irregular like a forehead, so I thought of animating it by using a force field animation and it pushes it against the object. But obviously when I reset the animation it goes back to its 'stiff' regular shape. Is there a way I could keep the animation frame as my default instead of sculpting or something?
I also want a way to make the cloth more taut[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMc80.png).
[image]

[image]